# Making LineRenderer Clickable with Raycast in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a project where I'm generating trees/plants with a line renderer and the l-system. Now I want to be able to click on the different plants to update their fitness score.

I tried to bake a mesh and use a mesh collider but it didn't work.

What would be the best way to approach this? Thank you in advance.

This is the part where I'm using the LineRenderer to generate the plants:

```html
public PlantDNA Generate(Bounds bounds)
    {
        Tree = Instantiate(treeParent);
        currentString = axiom;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //L-System 
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            foreach (var c in currentString)
            {
                // adds value onto string builder
                sb.Append(rules.ContainsKey(c) ? rules[c] : c.ToString());
            }
            currentString = sb.ToString();
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            //Debug.Log(currentString);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < currentString.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (currentString[i])
            {
                case 'F':
                    Vector3 initialPosition = transform.position;
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.up * 2 * length);

                    GameObject treeSegment = currentString[(i + 1) % currentString.Length] == 'X' || currentString[(i + 3) % currentString.Length] == 'F' && currentString[(i + 4) % currentString.Length] == 'X' ? Instantiate(leaf) : Instantiate(branch);
                    treeSegment.transform.SetParent(Tree.transform);
                    treeSegment.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(0, initialPosition);
                    treeSegment.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, transform.position);
                    treeSegment.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().startWidth = width;
                    treeSegment.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().endWidth = width;
                    break;
                // axiom
                case 'X':
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid L-Tree Operation");
            }
        }
        PlantDNA plant = Tree.AddComponent<PlantDNA>();
        AssignFirstPlantRule(plant);
        return plant;
    }
```

This is the fitness function with raycast:

```html
 public void FitnessFunction()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < population.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                RaycastHit hit;
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100.0f))
                {
                    if (hit.transform.gameObject == population[i].gameObject)
                    {
                        // Fitness Score um 1 erhöhen
                        population[i].fitnessScore += 1;
                        Debug.Log(population[i].fitnessScore);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

[plants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDa03.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need cahsed `treeSegment.GetComponent<LineRenderer>()` - its loaded method. Just
For raycast you needed *Collision component* and *RigitBody component on clickable object*. I see, you additing mesh collider. But are you addition RigitBody?